# Speech functionality not working in IFrame

Tags: botframework, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I have a bot client and in which I have enabled speech functionality.
Everything works fine when I open the bot client in new window.
Recently we have added this bot client site url in a page as IFrame.
In this all the functionalities are working fine except speech functionality.
When we are clicking on microphone icon nothing is happening.

Have tried in multiple browsers and devices, same issue in all the devices.
Windows - Chrome, IE
IPad,
IPhone

Is it the expected behavior? or Do i need to update anything?

Please let me know if you want me to share any code.

Code.

```
 speechOptions = {
        speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({
            subscriptionKey:
                'xxx'
        }),
        speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
            gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
            subscriptionKey: 'xxx'
            voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, ZiraRUS)'
        })
    };
    BotChat.App({
        botConnection: botConnection,
        user: { id: model.userId, Username: LoginUser,},
        bot: { id: model.botId, name: model.botName },
        resize: 'window',
        speechOptions: speechOptions,
        locale: 'en',
        sendTypingIndicator: true
    }, document.getElementById('BotChatElement'));

    botConnection
        .postActivity({
            from: user,
            name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
            type: 'event',
            value: ''
        })
        .subscribe(function (id) {
            console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
        });
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your HTML code with the iFrame?

Comment: ...And are you using the embed code of WebChat or one of the [WebChat samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few things you need to do in order to get speech working with WebChat.

1. Ensure that you are **not** using the version of WebChat with the embed code from the Azure Portal. You **must** use [one of the WebChat bundles](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list) (use one of the es5 bundles if you want it to work in IE)
2. [Speech Services are not supported on **many** version of major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition). Ensure that you and your users are only using supported browsers or [use Bing Speech](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.a.cognitive-services-bing-speech-js)
3. Chrome (and likely in the future, other browsers) [blocks microphone access until certain interactions occur first on the page/iFrame](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5687444770914304). You should be able to get around this with `<iframe allow="microphone *">`

Comment: @mdricgarson, have tried this option "allow="microphone *" no success :(

Comment: @SriramTamilarasan Can you link to the code you use for WebChat? I'll see if I can repro and come up with a fix.

Comment: Hi @mdrichardson, sorry for the delay.  I have added my code. Also this issue occurs in IOS Safari as well. Is there any property available to Safari browser?

Comment: @SriramTamilarasan I believe your issue is that you're using an older version of WebChat (BotChat). Please try with [one of the latest versions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list)